# Como posso fazer uma função que "chama" planilhas preexistentes no programa R?

Tags: r, funções

Bom dia, 
Sou novata como usuária do programa R portanto, estou com uma dúvida básica. Quero fazer uma função que utiliza uma planilha existente para puxar alguns dados que serão importantes para o cálculo que eu quero que a função realize. Como posso chamar essa planilha dentro da minha função?

Desde já, agradeço!

Comment: Natane, você tem algum código ou alguma coisa que tentou fazer para resolver o seu problema? Por que se não fica parecendo: façam por mim, por favor... entende? E a gente sabe que não é bem isso que você esta pedindo... :-)

Comment: Bem vinda ao [pt.so]. Faça o [tour] para saber como funciona o site.

Comment: A pergunta não é clara, mas há várias formas de chamar planilhas de Excel, Google Spreadsheet, Data Frame etc e atualizar os cálculos.